# Programming Newton's Method Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, newtons-method, python-3.6

For my assignment, we are required to create a program in which Newton's Method is calculated. There are a lot of techniques we haven't learned yet, which is why I am limited to how I design my code.

I especially need help on getting the actual Newton's Method to loop through according to the input I use for the number of iterations, but any advice would be happily taken.

```
def main():
    print("This program computes square roots through the Newton method")
    x = eval(input("Enter a number to calculate the square root of: "))
    r = eval(input("How many iterations should I use?: "))

    for i in range(1, r+1):
        guess = x/2
        for n in (1, r+1):
            n = (guess + (x/guess))/2   # Newton's Method formula
        import math
    y = math.sqrt(x)  # actual square root value

    for i in range(1, r+1):
        print(i, n, n-y)  # attempt at extra credit

    print("My guess for the square root of", x, "is", n)
    print("The difference between my guess and the actual result is:", n-y)


main()
```

This is due tonight...I misunderstood the assignment before so I thought I had it all figured out. Please help!

Comment: Why are you importing in a loop?  Move `import math` to top of file.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `for n in (1, r+1):`?

Comment: I am trying to use the for loop so that the Newton's formula will r amount of times. I am using the r+1 notation so that the answers will print out from [1,n] and not from 0. If it helps, I can post what the output of the formula should look like. Not sure if any of this makes sense, but I will try to clarify. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Well, for one you need only one for loop.  The second `for n in (1, r+1)` isn't a loop for r times, since you didn't include range.  It's just looping over `1` and `r+1`, and overwriting what you're trying to do to `n`.  You don't need to calculate "guess" in a loop, either.

Comment: You need to modify 'n' with the contents of n.  So try, maybe n = (n + x/n)/2 to update n?

Comment: Okay, good to know. I was just getting desperate because I know what I want the program to do and loop but I wasn't getting the desired output...it was a kind of Hail Mary of loops haha

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give you the entire answer, since this looks like a homework problem, but the core of your program is simply:

```
for i in range(r):
    n = (n + x/n)/2
```

Think about what n should start with.  Think about how you would print out answers as you generate them.